# Print lines followed by a line matching a pattern, to file A, if no match then print to file B

Tags: loops, perl, file-io

I am trying to write a Perl script to parse a file and segregate its contents based on a match criteria. A sample file (for e.g. test.txt) would look like something:

```
command something something keyword something something
filepath1
filepath2
command something something something something
filepath3
filepath4
filepath5
```

The output of the script would be two files based on the name of input file for the script, test.keyword and test.nomatch.

test.keyword would have something like this:

```
command something something keyword something something
filepath1
filepath2
```

test.nomatch would have something like this:

```
command something something something something
filepath3
filepath4
filepath5
```

The following is the skeleton that I have at the moment which is waiting for that golden loop condition:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -a

my $fh = shift or die "No file passed as argument for splitting!\n";
open( infile, "<$fh" ) or die $!;
open( vef_output, ">$fh.vef" ) or die $!;
open( svf_output, ">$fh.svf" ) or die $!;

$mode = 0; #0 for vef and 1 for svf

while ( my $line = <$infile> ) {
        if ( $line =~ /SOME_LIBRARY_OPTIONS/ ) {
        if ( $line =~ /\-sv/ ) {
            print {$svf_output} $line;
            $mode = 1;
        }
        else {
            print {$vef_output} $line;
            $mode = 0;
        }
        next;
    }
    if ( $mode eq 0 ) {
        print {$vef_output} $line;
        next;
    }
    else {
        print {$svf_output} $line;
        next;
    }   
}
close($vef_output);
close($svf_output);
close($file);
```

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut is a good start for regular expressions. You obviously need to find out if the line is a command line. And if so, if it also contains the keyword.

Comment: If at the beginning of your program you add `use strict; use warnings; use diagnostics;` You will get some valuable hints. Your logic is correct. Declare your variables with `my $variable`, use lexical filehandles with open `open( my $infile, '<', $fh)` and print using the lexical filehandles `print $svf_output $line;`

Comment: And important: remove that `-a` from your shebang line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the logic of your code is correct and you surely will find some remaining typos on your own, I would like to suggest a modification to your while loop:

Each line of your input file will have to be printed once (except perhaps for the beginning of the input file). Instead of setting a `$mode` flag and testing that, I'd rather switch the output filehandle , which leads to clearer code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = shift or die "No file passed as argument for splitting!\n";

# add filename to error message - users will like it!
open( my $infile, "<", $filename ) or die "could not open $filename: $!";
open( my $vef_output, ">","$filename.vef" )
    or die "could not open $filename.vef: $!";
open( my $svf_output, ">","$filename.svf" )
    or die "could not open $filename.svf: $!";

my $active_out;

while ( my $line = <$infile> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /SOME_LIBRARY_OPTIONS/ ) {
        $active_out = $vef_output;
    }
    # depending on your regex this conditional can be nested or not...
    if ( $line =~ /-sv/ ) {
        $active_out =  $svf_output;
    }
    next unless defined $active_out;
    print $active_out $line;
}

close($vef_output);
close($svf_output);
close($infile);
```

Comment: Thank you, @clamp
I rewrote my code along the same lines and it works for me now. The use strict and warnings helped, along with the change in the perl constructs that I was previously using.

Answer (score 1):

The code could be written in a simple more readable form

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# vim: ai ts=4 sw=4

use strict;
use warnings;

my $fh = shift
    or die "No file passed as argument for splitting!\n";

open my $in,          '<', $fh or die $!;
open my $out_match,   '>', $fh . 'vef' or die $!;
open my $out_nomatch, '>', $fh . 'svf' or die $!;

my $output_ready;
my $fh_out;

while ( <$in> ) {
        $output_ready = 1 if /SOME_LIBRARY_OPTIONS/;
        if( /-sv/ ) {
            $fh_out = $out_match;
        } else {
            $fh_out = $out_nomatch;
        }
        print $fh_out, $_ if $output_ready;
}

close $in;
close $out_match;
close $out_nomatch;
```